# Simplification of monomials

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing a course in EDX about differential equations and we had an exercise which is to find the general solution of this simple differential equation:

$\frac{dv}{dt} = 1 - v^{2}$

I can solve this until I reach this expression:

$\frac{1+v}{1-v} = c·e^{2t}$

The thing is that, in the solution that the course gives, they go from that expression, to this one:

$v=\frac{c·e^{2t}-1}{c·e^{2t}+1}$

Even I got a valid solution doing something a little bit different, I don't see how can I got the above expression from the previous one. I'm missing something very simple, I know, but I don't know what.

Many thanks.

Comment: I hope the course's solution mentioned that $v \equiv 1$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the $1-v$ denominator to move it to the right hand side, then add and subtract to group all $v$ terms on one side, factor out $v$ and divide the other factor on both sides.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1+v}{1-v} &= ce^{2t}\\
1+v &= ce^{2t} (1-v)\\
v+ce^{2t}v &= ce^{2t}-1\\
v &= \frac{ce^{2t}-1}{ce^{2t}+ 1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Use words when doing math: a sequence of equalities is always the worst possible way of writing any piece of math.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by the denominator and move $v$ to the LHS.
$$1+v = (1-v)c·e^{2t}$$
$$v(ce^{2t}+1)=ce^{2t}-1$$
$$v=\frac{c·e^{2t}-1}{c·e^{2t}+1}$$

Comment: Thanks! Got it finally.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it should has a trivial solution $v=\pm1$ and in fact this belongs to the singular solution.

And this can take limit on $c\to0$ and $\infty$ respectively from the general solution to obtain the singular solution.